# Display hidden buttons using JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single page theme created from scratch. I have One Main button and three sub-buttons in my page something like this

Home (displayed in the page)

```
 -New york (hidden)
 -Florida.(hidden)
 -Miami. (hidden)
```

What I want is if a client clicks home button it should display hidden buttons .

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you all for your supports, I found the solution:

```
<code>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#home_btn").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").show();

    });
});
</script>



<button onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden';" id="home_btn">home</button>

<div id="hidden">
<button>Newyork</button>
<button>Florida</button>
<button>Miami</button>
</div>


#hidden{
    display: none;
}

</code>
```

Comment: like a dropdown menu?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev no not like a drop down menu, something like this ,click zagraj iphone,  http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/4ik7o3u

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic: we don't use [solved] title amendments here. We also prefer self-answers to go in an answer box below (though we generally make exceptions if the question has been put on hold, since no new answers can be added).

Answer (score 3):

you can establish that using JS ,initially set `display:none;` for all hidden classes and set `display:block;` on click on home button using js.

```js
document.getElementById("home_btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    for(i =0;i < hidden.length ; i++){
        hidden[i].style.display = "block";
    }
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<button id="home_btn">home</button>
<button class="hidden">Newyork</button>
<button class="hidden">Florida</button>
<button class="hidden">Miami</button>
```

if you want to disappear home button after click, set display:none; for `#home_btn` on click.I'm added the snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById("home_btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("home_btn").style.display = "none";
    var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    for(i =0;i < hidden.length ; i++){
        hidden[i].style.display = "block";
    }
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<button id="home_btn">home</button>
<button class="hidden">Newyork</button>
<button class="hidden">Florida</button>
<button class="hidden">Miami</button>
```

Comment: Thank you , it works like charm !!! , If I want to make sure that the home button disappears after click  what should I do ..?

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic I'm added the snippet for disappear home button after click

Comment: Does not work disappear on click , I don't know why

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic check the second snippet,that will work

Comment: Thank you for ur help I found the simplest solution now works perfectly as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
$("#home").click(function() {
  $("#NewYork").show();
  $("#Florida").show();
  $("#Miami").show();
} )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="home">home</button>
    <button id="NewYork" hidden>1</button>
    <button id="Florida" hidden>2</button>
    <button id="Miami" hidden>3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add class using js.
in your css,

```
.db{
display: block;
}
```

In your js with jQuery library,

```
$( ".yourSelector" ).addClass( "db" );
```